# Smartest way to make an 180w SMPS?

Tags: power-supply, power, switch-mode-power-supply, charger, laptop

So i own this gaming laptop (MSI GX60) which draws a lot of power, the original charger i had recently broke, and i new one. But with that kind of power it costs around 60$ which is a bit much money for me at the moment.

So is it possible to make a relatively easy 180w power supply? I own a lot of linear regulators but since i'm going to use it as a laptop charger i really doubt that a linear one is the way to go because of the size and heat, The only power supply that is smps I've built is with the LM2678 regulator but that wasn't powerful enough.

Requirements:
19.5v output voltage.
9 - 10A output current.

How could you guys go about this? Thanks!

Comment: I'd wager you'd spend a whole lot more than $60 building your own - potentially frying your laptop along the way if you get it wrong.

Comment: I see, i thought it would be cheaper since i own a LOT of junk parts, but thanks for the tip, will look if i get some cheap used one then.

Answer (score 2):

Probably the smartest way to get a 200W 20V power supply is to shop for open-frame surplus at places like [this one](http://www.mpja.com/24-Volt-Power-Supply-10A-240W-Switching-Hengfu/productinfo/18436+PS/).

It will be difficult to get 20V, so get a 24V and tune down its feedback network, which you will need to figure out by yourself.

Alternatively, if you really have a stash of old junk, and do not particularly sensitive to design aesthetics, you can build a linear power supply. You will need a 300W 12-0-12 15A AC transformer, a 15A rectifier bridge, a 10,000uF x 35V sizable electrolytic cap, and 3-4 LT1038 or LM338 in parallel, in proper arrangement. And a square foot of 1/4" aluminum plate as a heat sink, or reuse slot-size forced air heat sinks from original Pentium-4 era.

Comment: Alright i might do that then, Closest thing i got with modifying a supply was with an old 350w atx PC power supply i have laying around. IT can supply over 15 amps at the 12v rail. My thought was to change tlll the capacitors to start with so that it can handle around 20v, and then modify the feedback part of the circuit to get 19.5v, but i just couldn't find the feedback part, My guess is that the feedback is in the SMD resistors and there are a LOT of them.. thread about it here:
http://forum.allaboutcircuits.com/threads/modify-atx-for-higher-output.126200/

Comment: Modifying multi-output PS (but with a single feedback) to jack up 12V to 20V is a challenging proposition. Many caps will need to be replaced for higher voltages, keeping ripple rating. Good luck.